# Mejorar el audio de java a una nueva versión

Tags: java

Hola buenas resulta que estoy haciendo un trabajo de logopedia y el problema viene con el audio le e añadido el paquete import java.applet.AudioClip;  pero esta en deprecated y me gustaria saber si hay algun formato de audio para java mucho mejor.

```
private void botonChupeteMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        AudioClip sonido;
        sonido = java.applet.Applet.newAudioClip(getClass().getResource("/audio/chupete.wav"));
        sonido.play();
    }
```

el sonido no falla pero lo quiero cambiar

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Java es?

Comment: la 14 el jdk vamos :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma es utilizar las clases del paquete [javax.sound.sampled](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/sound/sampled/package-summary.html) como en este ejemplo:

```java
import java.io.File;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;

public class PlaybackExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("./sound.wav");
            AudioFileFormat audioFileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(file);
            try (Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, audioFileFormat.getFormat()));
                 AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file)) {
                clip.open(audioInputStream);
                clip.start();
                clip.drain();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que hay varias *checked exceptions* que deben manejarse y que las clases `Clip` y `AudioInputStream` deberían cerrarse cuando vayan a dejar de usarse, una forma de hacerlo es usar un *try-with-resources* como en este ejemplo. Este ejemplo usa el método `drain()` para esperar hasta que termine la reproducción del sonido, esto puede no ser lo indicado en otras situaciones.

Comment: muchas gracias me has ayudado

Comment: una duda el javax.sound.sampled reproduce sonido mp3?